# Emacs Org-Mode: can I turn on the column-view on loading the file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to turn on the column-view (on the first topic) automatically when opening a certain .org file. Is there a possibility to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Switch to `column-veiw` on first  headline.

**test.org**

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (goto-char (point-min))
# eval: (outline-next-heading)
# eval: (org-columns)
# End:

* test A
* test B
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One way of doing is adding a file local variable for that org file.

```
    # Local Variables:
    # eval: (org-columns)
    # End:
```